# better phrase for 'brings clarity to'

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a a more powerful but still succinct phrase to replace 'brings clarity to'. It is being used in the context of "... brings clarity to this new cutting edge of positive psychology."

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Please tell us what research you've already done and what options you've considered.

Answer (score 2):

I would just replace 'brings clarity to' with 'clarifies' because I think less is more. Alternatively, we could go with 'delineates' or 'clearly delineates' or 'demystifies' or 'aptly demystifies' or 'efficaciously delineates' or 'efficaciously demystifies' or 'delineates with efficacy'.

Answer (score 0):

The word **elucidates** exists for exactly this purpose.

> to make lucid especially by explanation or analysis

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elucidates